# How to customize a segment of powerline(for Bash shell $PS1 layout, specifically)?

Tags: bash, json

According to the documentary, `powerline` use `~/.config/powerline/config.json` for configurations. Since I don't quite like the layout of `$PS1` by default, I made some change in keyword `cwd` as following. However, the customization wasn't applied. Did I do something wrong? Generally, how to customize a segment in `powerline`?

```
{
    "powerline":{
        "segments":{
            "shell":{
                "cwd":{
                    "dir_shorten_len": 4,
                    "dir_limit_depth": 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify one of the theme config files in `config-directory/themes/` (presumably `~/.config/powerline/themes/` on your system)

One way to do it is to put something like this in `config-directory/themes/shell/__main__.json`

```
{
    "segment_data": {
        "cwd": {
            "args": {
                "dir_shorten_len": 4,
                "dir_limit_depth": 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That sets the default arguments for the `cwd` function when called from the `shell` extension, but you can still override with a different argument in the theme config file.

e.g., `config-directory/themes/shell/default.json`:

```
{
    "segments": {
        "left": [
            ...other-segments...
            {
                "function": "powerline.segments.shell.cwd",
                "priority": 10,
                "args": {
                    "dir_shorten_len": 1,
                    "dir_limit_depth": 5
                }
            }
        ],
        "right": [
            ...right-segments...
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, in addition to `powerline.segments.shell.cwd`, there is also the more general `powerline.segments.common.env.cwd`.  For that function, you could put default args in `config-directory/themes/powerline.json`, which would affect not only the `shell` extension, but any others that use `powerline.segments.common.env.cwd`.

Note that calls to `powerline.segments.shell.cwd` still respect `powerline.segments.common.env.cwd` default args, unless overridden somewhere more specific.

Comment: Thanks. It works. And do you know some good material to learn about setting powerline properly?

Comment: I've just been reading the official docs (https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and googling anything that's not clear in the docs, which aren't the easiest to follow unfortunately.  That's how I came upon this post.

At this point I'm considering switching back to vim-airline (https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and the agnoster zsh theme (https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874), which gives you something similar to powerline in vim/zsh at least.

Comment: Powerline has lots of cool features but it's a little too complicated (and a little slow) for something that just provides prompts. I like the idea of being able to write new segments in python, but I'm not sure if it's worth it.